# Dart pub get command is not working properly when i try to pull my dependencies

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I have my project in github. I already created it like a library (Dart). Now I am trying to use my library in one of my project.

After i add all the necessary comments to get it from my git source, pub get is giving the following error,

Warning: `Package <library_name> does not have a "lib" directory so you will not be able to import any libraries from it.`
Got dependencies!

Any clue???

Thanks,
Tham

Comment: Can you please provide more information.
How looks your package structure like (directories), provide your pubspec.yaml of the library package and the project you want to import the library to.

Answer (score 1):

When importing libraries, the files you import come from the `lib` folder.

Eg:

```
import 'package:danny/danny.dart';
```

will import the file `lib/danny.dart` from the `danny` package.

If the package doesn't have a `lib` folder; this means you can't possibly import it. If you're importing directly from a Git repo; you need to ensure the `lib` folder is a top-level folder.